# Remove many-to-one relationship - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 classes, class A with the follwing relationship:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aaa", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<B> bbb = new ArrayList<B>();
```

and class B:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "aaa", nullable = false)
private A aaa;
```

However when I try to delete an entity of class B nothing happens. I'm not getting any errors and no SQL-Statements get executed.

```
B b = em.find(B.class, id)
em.remove(b);
```

Anything I am obviously doing wrong here?

Comment: Nothing happens as in "it is not deleted from B table" or as in "the relation to A is not followed"?

Comment: Nothing happens as in "it is not deleted from B table". Table A doesnt hold any information about B.

Comment: Are you in a transactional context? Do you commit the delete?

Comment: Im beginning a transaction, removing b, comitting and closing the entity manager, nothing else

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: Absolutely no exceptions. If I try to delete "a" everything works fine. The cascading works and both get deleted from the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it,

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "aaa",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
private List<B> bbbb;
```

and here you create Setter and Getter methods of `List<B>` in bean class.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="aaa")
    private A aaa;
```

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: can you show me error log. may be i will help you !